# Re-rendering React on each PJAX load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, page-refresh, pjax, swup

*I will preface this by noting that I am using an Eleventy-esque project called Slinkity that enables React component capabilities and uses ReactDOM in the browser.*

- Simplified project repo [Here](https://github.com/kylesloper/slinkity-pjax)
- Live demo [Here](https://mf-slinkity-pjax.surge.sh/)

I am attempting to implement a PJAX system into my Slinkity project but I'm running into a few issues on the React side. On each PJAX page load, all reactive components do not work until a full page refresh (which obviously breaks the PJAX mentality).

Can anyone suggest a way to efficiently re-render React components on each PJAX load - assuming of course that this is the best way to go about it.

Thanks in advance, let me know if I can offer any more info.

Comment: https://github.com/slinkity/slinkity/issues/160